# Cloudinary make an image transformation public?

Tags: cloudinary

I am not sure if this is possible in Cloudinary. I have a flow where I upload an image and apply different transformations.
These images and their transformations are private. For one specific case, I want the transformation to make the image public. These images also have a signed URL.

Is this possible, with a transformation to make the image public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely something possible within Cloudinary. The easiest way to get this done would simply be to use a different Upload Preset when uploading files that you want to be public.

If you're wanting to make certain assets public based on certain criteria such as specific characteristics about the image/video you've uploaded (such as width/height, aspect ratio, etc), you may be better off using Cloudinary [MediaFlows](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/mediaflows_user_guide). This allows you to take the upload response and perform actions based on the results.

For a more granular level of control, you could always use an [upload notification URL](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/notifications). This will return the upload response JSON to a script on your server, allowing you to perform further actions.

I hope this helps. If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to reach our to Cloudinary's support team by [raising a support ticket](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).